# How can we secure communication of an unchangeable app (Zoom)?

Tags: network

During the COVID-19 pandemic, many of us are working from home using meeting apps like Zoom. It's all over the news that Zoom is lacking in its E2E encryption. Let's assume we're using Zoom and can't switch apps.

Considering only the traffic, how can we make these meetings secured/encrypted?

The solution can be hard on 1 group (the company using Zoom) but should be easy on the users (employees of the company). My 1st thought here is to have the company set up a VPN server (in the company or with a 3rd party) and have everyone connect to the VPN before joining a meeting.

Comment: To downvoters: Please leave a comment explaining why you think this question doesn't show any research effort, is unclear or not useful.

Comment: "secured/encrypted" against what threats? VPN only addresses a part of the problem. What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: I did not understand VPNs and models with 3rd parties enough when I asked this question...

Comment: Ultimately, if you're really worried about the video conferencing app, either find a more respectable provider or host your own. There are a few self-hosted video conference solutions out there, such as Jitsi. I have not used these so I cannot recommend anything yet.

Comment: Both ends must talk in code

Comment: Is there a de facto secure video conferencing app?  I guess if a company is large enough they would use their own proprietary system.

Comment: Do you really need E2E encryption? Most software does not have that feature and people are quite happy to use it. I can't tell from your question if you understand what E2E encryption is, or if you think Zoom meetings are not encrypted at all, although I'm leaving towards the latter. No-one makes much fuss about WebEx not having E2E.

Comment: Any system that has to talk to a telecom network has to deliver a fully unencrypted conversation at some point to implement the classic call-in option.  Zoom servers have to have the encryption keys in order to send and receive audio to call-in users.  There's no way around that.  Jitsi and other services have the same problem and solve it in exactly the same way.  Jitsi has a self-hosted option though whereas Zoom, Teams, etc. do not.

Comment: I thought I could contribute a hypothetical idea.. If you could hijack both webcams, you could feed an encrypted stream into Zoom

Comment: @codeninja: While you could feed encrypted video this way this does not magically shows decrypted at the endpoint. Apart from the client lacking the necessary capabilities the __video compression is lossy__ and also gets further processed on the server. This makes it practically impossible to restore the original encrypted stream and decrypt it.

Comment: " Let's assume we're using Zoom and can't switch apps." - Except as a theoretical curiosity, this restriction isn't very useful without more context. Perhaps there could be some way to transmit a relatively low quality, encrypted video stream over zoom and decrypt it at the other end. But if all parties need to configure some elaborate and awkward software, it's not clear why that's not harder than using something other than zoom...

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer your question but here are some tips by Mozilla to make zoom as private as possible: https://foundation.mozilla.org/en/blog/tips-make-your-zoom-gatherings-more-private/

Comment: Keep in mind that E2E with clients produced by who offers the service is *exactly* the same as not having E2E. E2E makes sense only if you can use a client that **you** control, so that you can ensure that they do not sniff the unencrypted data at the endpoints. So it's basically just PR for most use cases. Also: Zoom got special attention now because was *the* application that skyrocketed. I bet that most other platforms have similar security issues.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You cannot magically secure applications like Zoom without changing the application and the infrastructure it relies on.

The missing end-to-end encryption you want to have fixed is due to the basic architecture of Zoom, in which media streams are processed and mixed together on a central server (which is owned by Zoom). Only this architecture actually allows it to perform well without stressing bandwidth and CPU of endpoints when many users are involved. With E2E instead the requirements for CPU and bandwidth at each end would grow linearly with the number of users and thus would quickly overwhelm clients.

These kind of restrictions apply to any video conferencing solution. This means that you will not get real E2E with any other solution too, at least not if you want conferences which scale to many users without having excessive requirements regarding bandwidth and CPU power. The best you can get is that you control the central mixing and forwarding server yourself and thus don't need to trust a third party.

Even the broken AES ECB mode could not be fixed without changing application and infrastructure since the server actually expects the encryption to be a specific way and if you change it the communication will fail.

Usage of a VPN would not magically solve the problem. The data would still need to be processed on the servers owned by Zoom.

Comment: What if you encrypt all the communications between your company server and the Zoom server?

Comment: @nick012000 That’s not E2E. And also requires Zoom to support _your_ chosen method of encryption at their end - which they won’t. Remember that people want a way to video-chat with groups of people WITHOUT Zoom being able to see the contents of the stream - which reduces Zoom to being just a “dumb” packet-router (I.e. you could replace the video-chat stream with an arbitrary file-transfer stream and they wouldn’t be able to tell) - in which case just use IPv6 with IPSec and a simple P2P streaming app (can’t *easily* use IPv4 with home users due to NAT). Zoom’s value is in their convenience.

Comment: @nick012000 You cannot do it because it would require modification of the zoom client and zoom server but zoom can encrypt the communications by modifying their client and server code

Comment: @TheD: *"Zoom’s value is in their convenience."* - that's only one value. The other value is that Zoom is actually mixing the data for which it needs to access the streams. But without this mixing every endpoint would need to receive all audio and video from the current participants which means bandwidth requirements for each endpoint increase linearly with the number of streams and CPU must be able to handle all these streams too. [This site](https://testrtc.com/different-multiparty-video-conferencing/) has a good comparison of Mesh vs. SFU vs. MCU architecture for conferencing.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Or ISPs could let us use IP multicast on the public Internet, thus clients' upstream bandwidth and audio+video encoding performance requirements are constant and only downstream bandwidth matters.

Comment: @TheD:  Each client has only its locally produced audio and video for upstream but gets the audio and video from all others as downstream. Multicast would not change these bandwidth requirements at each endpoint in any way. It would at most require less bandwidth on some routers which are shared by multiple clients. Moreover multicast would require to have a shared encryption key between multiple endpoints.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich But IP Multicast eliminates the need for a central MCU or SFU. In cases where the central AV muxing capabilities of an MCU do save on total bandwidth (e.g. using a lower video res and bitrate for "background" participants vs. "podium" participants) then the same can be achieved with IP multicast by having (for example in this case) two upstreams from each peer: a low-bandwidth baseline stream, and a "high-pass" (high-bandwidth) stream (which wouldn't include redundant info from the low-bandwidth stream), clients would then send only the low-bw or both streams (assuming trust!)

Comment: @TheD: A MCU merges the media from all endpoints, so the bandwidth and CPU requirements on each endpoint are independent from the number of participants. In your proposal the requirements on each endpoint are still dependent on the number of participants, no matter if multicast or not. Multicast does not make any difference on the endpoint, it makes only a difference on routers shared by multiple endpoints. Basically your proposal is better than a dumb mesh but it still has more requirements to the endpoints than a MCU.

Comment: In principle it *is* possible to transmit E2E encrypted messages using Zoom: just encrypt your message locally and encode it somehow in the video stream. It is the same idea as using an insecure chat medium such as Whatsapp or Skype to exchange encrypted messages (e.g. off-the-record messaging). In principle, with sufficient bandwidth, it is even possible to transmit encrypted video (though with very low resolution). It would even be possible to write a webcam driver that does all this automatically. (I know, all this is ridiculously impractical.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I think you've missed the point of the question. This is about somehow fixing the insecurity of Zoom without changing the app and while providing the original functionality. Your idea either makes changes to the app necessary or does not longer provide the functionality.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich What I suggest does not require *changes* to the Zoom app, only additional tools that interface with it. But I understand that OP's requirements are fuzzy enough that it is not clear if this is allowed or not.

Comment: You could have an E2E encryption video call by sharing a key between all connected clients. Only the key-exchange between those needs to be scaled by number of participants, not the actual encryption of the video. (Of course, if you want a server to mix data together and doing stuff like "show the video of whoever is currently speaking big, and the others small", then it doesn't work without the server having the key.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: what you describe as an SFU architecture where the downstream bandwidth on each endpoint grows linearly with the number of clients and thus does not scale well to many clients. See my comments and links above about this topic.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann suggested using a shared key. I think that is enough. All the server needs to know is who is speaking at each point in time, not what each is speaking. So you do not need to transmit all streams to everyone in the group. This clearly scales well to many clients.

Comment: @user21820: If the server cannot do mixing then then each clients needs to do mixing - which means that the client needs to receive the streams from all other clients (if all should be mixed together)  and thus the required bandwidth increases with the number of peers. If the server can do mixing then each client receives a mixed result which has the same bandwidth no matter how much clients are there. But, in order to do the mixing the server must have the data unencrypted, i.e. must have the encryption key, must decrypt the original data, must encrypt the mixed data. This is no E2E anymore.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: No. You do **not** need to mix. You just need to algorithmically decide which (encrypted) stream to broadcast, by knowing **who** is speaking, **not what** they speak. This is not hard to get right at all.

Comment: @user21820: I'm not sure if you've ever used a state of the art video conference. It is pretty common that you'll see and hear many or even all of the participants at once and not just a single one. And this requires mixing - either at each client or at some central server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: There is little point in seeing and hearing more than k people talk at the same time, for some small k. All that the algorithm has to decide is which k are the ones most important to transmit in high resolution. All the rest can be transmitted in low resolution. The bandwidth usage would be dominated by k times the high-resolution bandwidth required per stream. Whatever details you pick, the basic fact remains that you do not need much information to know who to focus on at each point. Humans do this all the time. Poor software does not make it impossible...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106614/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-user21820).

Answer (score 5):

*TL;DR: Specifically for Zoom, take a look at [Zoom Meeting Connector](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/sections/200305473-Meeting-Connector)*

First off, to get it out of the way, **encrypted** is not the same as **secure**, and **secure** can be vague depending context.

As schroeder♦ have commented, you need to be clear on what you are actually trying to achieve, what threats you are defending against. Only then you may determine if a solution  really solve your problem. It might turn out E2E encryption isn't what you actually need, or want. And like Steffen Ullrich said, you can't just magically add that without significant changes to both its application and infrastructure.

Fortunately, in the case of Zoom, there is a relatively easy way out (depending on you actual needs). Zoom allows you to run your own server for streaming audio and video, while still using Zoom server for other management tasks.

(From https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201363113-Meeting-Connector-Core-Concepts)

> Zoom offers a public or hybrid cloud service. In the hybrid cloud service,  you deploy meeting communication servers known as the Zoom Meeting Connector within your company's internal network. In doing so, user and meeting metadata are managed in the public cloud while the meetings are hosted in your private cloud. All meeting traffic including video, voice and data sharing goes through the on-premise Zoom Meeting Connector.
>
> [image: Meeting connector]

This way, the conference data stays in a server you control. Even if you makes call from outside internal network, the traffic is still encrypted in transit and only decrypted on (your) meeting server. Deployment should not be difficult for a corporate IT team, though might be challenging for laymen. If you want the privacy of E2EE, this is about as close as you can get without actually changing the software or rolling you own service.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible to make E2E encrypted connections with Zoom, your company  can probably use an open-source and self-hosted solution like Jitsi. It encrypts the connections between the participants and the server, and only the participants and the server will have the data unencrypted.

So, because you can host the server wherever you want, if you control both the clients and the server you control your data.

Of course, if you use an instance that you don't control, you have to make trust in the instance owner. Similarly, if you use Zoom Meeting Connector , you still have to trust Zoom to not leak - voluntarily or not - your audio. (not saying they will - that's just a possibility)

(From a usability point of view, Jitsi is quite similar to Zoom, although not as feature full, but it works really well)

Answer (score -4):

A somewhat trite answer - don't use zoom's native software..

Instead - look around for the "dial-in number" and call the meeting using a regular telephone.

Downsides, you won't get the video stream, and the user creating the meeting has to be in credit and a paying customer.  These are not available in the free accounts.

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362663-Joining-a-meeting-by-phone

Also consider that other participants in the meeting may remain vulnerable, so your words could still become exposed.  And any meeting recording will carry your input too.

Comment: That does not provide E2E either. The audio is still centrally processed by Zooms server.

Comment: Moreover the incoming call is trivially snooped for an analogue landline, easily snooped for a digital one, and relatively easily snooped these days for GSM. So this makes security worse than Zoom over IP rather than better.

Comment: Other ideas along the same lines: Don't use Zoom at all. Don't use videoconferencing software. Don't try to communicate with people outside your home. Just don't say a word anymore. People won't hear what you are not saying. Problem solved.

Comment: What threat is this supposed to address? Why is the phone number supposed to be better? You do not explain that part at all. And since it is all going to Zoom anyway, I'm not sure there is a benefit when the OP is considering the transmission as the subject under threat.

Comment: @Relaxed that's a separate answer, not a comment on this answer.

Comment: @schroeder this answer addresses the protection of your own computer/device and by extension anything on it, and your home LAN.   As per answer, this does not protect your words.

Comment: @abligh You are totally correct that telephone calls have been snoop-able since forever.  However that's a different vector and would require a different approach, rather than employing the existing holes in Zoom's protocols, designs and implementation.

Comment: @abligh i'm really curious, how do you trivially snoop an analog landline? i'd assume you'd need to break into a wiring cabinet and locate the line on the patch panel, while with GSM you just stand somewhere with an antenna. are there tricks i don't know about?

Comment: @user371366 yes - re landline, with access to signal in transit (either a cabinet that's unlocked, or better because you either are the telecoms company or a subcontractor or can pretend to be) you have the raw unencrypted signal. For encrypted digital comms (whether end to end or not) you need both access, and either the ability to decrypt or the ability to access at a non-encrypted point - so it's strictly harder.

Comment: @Criggie No, no, it really is a (sarcastic) comment. I don't think either answer (yours or mine) have any merit. Mine was supposed to illustrate what's wrong with your logic.